# Time-series regression using the dependent variable as an independent one

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, predictive-models

Suppose I have a well-performing time-series regression such as:

$$
x_{2020} = \beta_0 + \beta_{2019}x_{2019} + \beta_{2018}x_{2018} + \beta_{2017}x_{2017}
$$

Having fit this regression to $x_{2020}$, I'd now like to use it to predict $x_{2021}$.  How could I now use $x_{2020}$ as an independent variable?  My initial thought was to shift the variables so that $x_{2019}$ would get $\beta_{2018}$'s weight, but I don't think it's that simple since my predictions for $x_{2021}$ look a bit odd.

Thanks.

P.S: Sorry if this is a duplicate; the closest I could find are [Time series regression coefficient interpretation with differenced independent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194259/time-series-regression-coefficient-interpretation-with-differenced-independent-v) and [How to account for the recency of the observations in a regression problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454415/how-to-account-for-the-recency-of-the-observations-in-a-regression-problem) but I'm not sure they're what I'm looking for.

Comment: Another possible duplicate is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205232/how-to-down-weight-older-data-in-time-series-regression but I don't know that I want to down-weight older data...

Comment: This is called an autoregression. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/AR.html.

Comment: Probably want to learn about lag operators and difference operators.

Comment: Thanks @RobHyndman and Alexis, but doesn't AR require an observation every time period?  Like sometimes I have data for 2018 but not always, and it's not missing at random.

Comment: No, you can fit an autoregression with missing observations.

Comment: Wow, I definitely need to read more about this.  Your book has some good examples that help me think about how to work with my data.  Thank you :)